# can't install node express on windows 10

Tags: node.js, express, npm, web-frameworks

I am trying to set up a node express development environment on windows 10. I have successfully installed node.js and npm but when I try to install express using:

```
npm init
npm install express
```

I get the following error:

```
npm WARN myapp@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN myapp@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\mi292519\Dropbox\selfLearning\nodeJs\myapp\node_modules\bytes
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\mi292519\Dropbox\selfLearning\nodeJs\myapp\node_modules\.bytes.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\mi292519\Dropbox\selfLearning\nodeJs\myapp\node_modules\bytes' -> 'C:\Users\mi292519\Dropbox\selfLearning\nodeJs\myapp\node_modules\.bytes.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mi292519\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-07T11_17_07_099Z-debug.log
```

I tried removing node_modules and package.json also tried deleting npm-cache and npm install again but none of that worked

any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @Michael: Please copy here the error log.

Comment: my apologies, I have now included the error message

Comment: Is this related? https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20175

Comment: Have you tried doing this outside of your dropbox folder ?

Comment: @virtual_Black_Whale No, I haven't but I can try

Comment: @virtual_Black_Whale Yes,  a simple ```npm install express``` outside my dropbox got it to work. Thank you! Oh the hours I spent trying to figure this out!